# Ansible - Server/application initiated reboot

Tags: ansible

I want to use Ansible for software upgrade of a remote server (BSD unix based). At the end of the upgrade, system reboots automatically (this reboot is not initiated by Ansible). I want to make sure ansible will wait for the server to come back and then continue other tasks. Script works fine for the upgrade but fails during reboot (complained about ssh shared connection failure).

script1:

```
- hosts: remote_server 
  remote_user: ansible
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  connection: ssh
  gather_facts: yes
  vars:
     ansible_ssh_host: 192.168.1.131
     ansible_ssh_port: 22 
  tasks:
  - name: Install SW version xxx
    ....
    ....

  - name: waiting for server to reboot
    wait_for: host="{{ ansible_ssh_host | default(inventory_hostname) }}" port={{ ansible_ssh_port | default(22) }} search_regex=OpenSSH delay=60 timeout=300 
    connection: local
    sudo: false  

  - shell: uptime
    register: output
  - debug: msg=" {{ output.stdout }} "
```

Any idea what I am missing here? Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

So during that reboot, normally you would get a failure.  You an use a meta task like this to ignore the failure

```
- meta: clear_host_errors
```

After that you could use a waitfor, and then continue any tasks.

```
- name: Wait for system to become reachable
  wait_for_connection:
    timeout: 300
```

Comment: I added below lines as suggested but still getting failure: - meta: clear_host_errors

  - name: (reboot) Wait for server to restart
    wait_for_connection:
      timeout: 180 
 
  - shell: uptime
    register: output
  - debug: msg=" {{ output.stdout }} "

Comment: Maybe edit the error you are getting into your question?

Comment: Here is the error: fatal: [192.168.1.131]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Shared connection to 192.168.1.131 closed.\r\n", "unreachable": true}

Comment: Looks like server disconnects before it can run the wait command. Since it is application initiated reboot I cannot add code like below which are usually done when Ansible give reboot command: - name: reboot the server
      shell: sleep 2 && shutdown -r now
      async: 1
      poll: 0

Comment: Maybe add a `pause: minutes:2` or something like that before the clear connection task.